# How to write null condition in a beautiful way using kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to write a null check code in a fancy way . Is there a better way to write? Some sample or tips will be great! I would love to hear from you!

```
if (list != null) {
    myData = list[0]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more functional style of writing this is using `let` together with the `?` operator:

```
list?.let { myData = it[0] }
```

Using `?`, `let` is only called if 'list' is not `null` and `list` is passed  as the only parameter to the lambda.

Comment: Additionally, when you need else branch, you can simply put `?: "some else value"` after brace end: `list?.let { myData = it[0] } ?: myData = "some else value"` and having this, you can even make it better by moving `myData` to the beginning: `myData = list?.let { it[0] } ?: "some else value"`